# Weird JCompnent visual error in java

Tags: java, graphics, jcomponent

I'm currently learning java and I've gotten stuck on this problem for a while now.
I have reinstalled java (the latest version, 1.8.0_25) but the problem still persists.

Whenever I try to add anything visual from the JComponent class it gets this weird error and I can't figure out what's causing it.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello!");
        JButton button = new JButton("Click me!");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("woah");
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(12);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(250, 250);

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();

        p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        p1.add(textField);
        p1.add(label);

        p2.add(button);

        frame.add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }


}
```

[And here is a link to a picture of the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMqRB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Start by making sure you start your program within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details.
- Don't make the window visible until you've prepared it's initial view
- Don't rely on magic numbers (`frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3)`), they have little meaning to most people and the value could be changed, use a constant instead, for example `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`

For example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello!");
                JButton button = new JButton("Click me!");
                JLabel label = new JLabel("woah");
                JTextField textField = new JTextField(12);

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
                JPanel p2 = new JPanel();

                p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

                p1.add(textField);
                p1.add(label);

                p2.add(button);

                frame.add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                frame.add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

There is also an issue with Java 8 on some machines, but this should rectify "most" of them...

Comment: It didn't fix the problem, but I tested on another machine and it worked fine so I guess it is the issue with java 8 you were talking about. Thank you for the quick answer!